# How can I update the array package? Warning from tabu

Tags: miktex, memoir, incompatibility, arrays, tabu

I am trying to use the `tabu` package, but it returns a warning which does not seem like a good sign. Does anyone know how to resolve the following issue?

> LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 68, version
>   '2008/09/09' of package array, but only version '2008/07/23' is
>   available.

I am using MikTex on windows and I have updated my complete MikTex library with the update manager, but the warning still occurs.

*UPDATE*
It seems to be a bit more complicated than I thought. The `array` package requested is emulated by the `memoir` package.

The log file outputs:

> Package array [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.

This is my preamble, which I hope is sufficient:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mscthesis}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

Comment: What version of MiKTeX are you using?

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct answer, but it says: `MikTex Package Manager 2.9.4196`.

Comment: The answer then is that you have an old `array.sty` file hanging somewhere.

Comment: And what would be correct ways to fix this? Could you name a couple of folders where I can check for that? And if I have found it, should I just delete it?

Comment: In the log file resulting from the LaTeX run you should find a reference to `array.sty`, with the complete path of the file. Can you see it?

Comment: I have updated my question. It seems that the array package is emulated by the memoir-class.

Comment: @Marnix i think egreg is right.  the miktex distribution definitely has the correct version of array.sty (i just checked on the archive).  to find the rogue array.sty, find the .log file from your latex run: the place where it reports loading array.sty gives you the full path to the file.

Comment: @wasteofspace Yes, it seemed that the array package was emulated by memoir, but other errors still occur after egreg's solution. (see comment)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The manual of `memoir` says that emulated package can be "disemulated", so the instructions

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\DisemulatePackage{array}
\usepackage{array}
```

should do the job (I omit options and other packages just for the sake of brevity). However, it doesn't seem to work for `array`, because some errors are raised about already defined things, for example

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \extratabsurround already defined.
```

You have two strategies: ignore the warning raised by `tabu` or say

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@array.sty}{2008/09/09}
\makeatother
```

so that the warning won't be raised by `tabu` nor the errors mentioned before will appear. It's quite curious that `memoir` sets the date `2008/07/23`, as version 2.4b of `array` is dated 2005/08/23 and version 2.4c has date 2008/09/09. So I believe there is no risk of incurring in issues, provided the emulation is full (which it should be).

---

Notice that `times` and `pslatex` are obsolete packages. Use `mathptmx` or try

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a logical move, but it returns errors for commands that are already defined. Example: `! LaTeX Error: Command \extratabsurround already defined.` I cannot find from which package this errors comes.

Comment: @Marnix I've changed the answer. I would simply keep the annoying warning, but I suggested a way to avoid it anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that works. How should I indicate the problem to the maintainer of `memoir`? I don't know who that is. I'm just using a template from my university.

Comment: @daleif Can you look into this, please?

Comment: @Marnix The previous comment is addressed to the mantainer (who happens to be around here).

Comment: @egreg: I'll have a look. Could someone provide a full minimal example instead of these sniplets?

Comment: @daleif The minimal example is just the first three codelines in my answer: add `\begin{document}` and enjoy the errors. :) The problem seems to be that `array` is too important for `memoir`, so it's assumed as loaded and can't be disemulated. Probably a fix to the date is just what's needed (with a warning in the manual about the impossibility of disemulating `array`).

Comment: I think disemulating can only be done if the code is written to overwrite. `memoir` does notthing special when the user ask to disemulate. In some cases functionality similar to some package is provided, but under other internal names. In that case disemulating will work fine. But `array` is almost a verbatim copy

Comment: @daleif That's what I suspected. So it's better to make it clear in the manual and check against the latest version of `array` if the copy is really updated (I believe it is).

Comment: Just got around to do a diff between array 2.4b from 2005 and 2.4c from 2008. The only difference is apparently copyright years. Emulated data updated in development sources. Release date unknown.